# Why would I want to limit the size of the ".data" segment?

Tags: ulimit

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42554805/8446) on StackOverflow, it says:

> For example on Linux, if you initialize the data within the source (instead of reading a file at runtime) the data will be stored in a .data segment. The size of this segment can be limited by kernel options. You can find the current limit with ulimit -d.

On both my Linux and macOS boxes, I get:

```
$ ulimit -d
unlimited
```

Why might I want to configure a limit to the size of the .data segment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ulimit -d` sets the maximum size of a *process*'s data segment, not just the maximum size of a *binary*'s .data segment. You'd use it to limit the amount of memory that a process can use; as per [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html):

> `RLIMIT_DATA`
>
> This is the maximum size of a data segment of the process, in bytes. If this limit is exceeded, the *malloc()* function shall fail with *errno* set to [ENOMEM].

The limit applies to binaries in that a process whose data segment has been limited will not be able to `exec` a binary with a .data segment which is larger than the data segment limit. The limit continues to apply after that though, so that the data segment can not grow beyond the limit while the process is running.

Like all limits, this is relevant in a number of scenarios. On a multi-user system, you'd set limits up so that a single user can't monopolise the system's resources, or affect other users' ability to use the system. You can also set limits so that a single process can't monopolise the system's resources (*e.g.* a web browser, or a large build...). Nowadays you're probably better off using something like cgroups on a Linux system for this kind of resource control.